# Storing Credit Card Numbers

Tags: encryption, pci-dss, confidentiality

I'll be making a website with a membership type of option for the website, and I'll be most likely using Authorize.Net to make the transactions, however, I need to know what kind of encryption I can use to store credit card numbers in a MySQL database?

Comment: If you have to ask this question, you probably shouldn't be storing credit card numbers. Outsource this if at all possible.

Comment: If you can't properly handle them, why store them at all? Save them somehow during the transaction and then delete all data about them. Renewing membership is a bitch, but loosing all members because you failed to ensure that your security was proper is worse.

Comment: What country are you in ?

Comment: @ManseUK - What does it matter what country he is in?  Storing the credit cards is the same problem in any country

Comment: >"If you have to ask this question" even if you didn't, if the option to load PCI-DSS on someone else is available, take it.

Answer (score 14):

Why even store it in a MySQL database when you can be using [Authorize.Net's Customer Information Manager API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/) and taking PCI compliance and security issues right out of your hands completely and letting them do all of the heaving lifting for you? CIM let's you create customer payment profiles by storing the customer's credit card information on their end and then charging against that profile at a future date whenever you need to simply by referring to the payment profile ID at the time of the transaction.

Answer (score 12):

The key regulation you **must** follow is the [Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS)](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf) and of specific interest here is section 3.4 -

**Protect Stored Cardholder Data**

Render PAN unreadable anywhere it 
is stored (including on portable digital 
media, backup media, and in logs) by 
using any of the following approaches:

- One-way hashes based on strong 
  cryptography (hash must be of the 
  entire PAN)
- Truncation (hashing cannot be used 
  to replace the truncated segment of 
  PAN)
- Index tokens and pads (pads must 
  be securely stored)
- Strong cryptography with associated 
  key-management processes and 
  procedures

The rest of section 3 is also worth reading in depth!

Comment: As pointed out above, the bottom line from that is that you don't want to have to follow PCI-DSS if you don't have to. Definitely better off outsourced.

Answer (score 2):

It probably (see note below) satisfies the requirements if you use a well-known symmetric cipher (such as AES or blowfish/twofish) on the sensitive data using a key stored someplace not accessible from the database. Since the result is non-printable, you can either hex or base64 encode the result for storage.

Obviously any system that does automatic encryption and decryption is going to be inherently less secure than a manual system, as the keys will have to be stored right there on the server for the thing to work. But the more you can separate them, the better.

Better yet, many gateway providers allow for mechanisms where you do not have to store the customer's card on your server, including Authorize.net's CIM and Paypal's Reference Transactions just to name a couple of examples.

**Note**: *This does not constitute legal or security advice and should not be interpreted as such. You should always hire a local security professional if you have questions or concerns.*

Comment: While I 100% agree with the higher ranked answers about outsourcing the responsibility if possible.  I like that this one actually answers the question.  I am curious though based on the age of this answer if AES is still considered cryptographically secure.